# Remove series from chart when user clicks on legend?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

You should know that I am new to Highcharts, so if my code or question seem weird, let me know.

Users can add data series to a chart.

When users click on the legend of a data series, that data series get's hidden from the chart and the legend get's grayed out. I want to change this behavior so that when users click on the legend of a data series, that data series should be completely removed from the chart, not only hidden.

I tried by writing the following code in highcharts-graph.js:

```
plotOptions: {
                line: {

                    events: {
                        legendItemClick: function () {
                            this.remove(true);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

This code removes the legend. But when a user adds another data series to the chart, the legend of the deactivated data series re-appears. So I believe that I need to modify the code to remove the data series instead of the legend.

Comment: Do you have an example, e.g. jsfiddle?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I'm not good enough at this to create fully functioning stand-alone examples yet. The code above does remove the clicked legend. But I need it to remove the clicked data series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid error being thrown `legendItemClick` function could return `false`. To avoid same names or mixed indexes for series, it is possible to set names and indexes for new series.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jct0msdt/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        plotOptions: {
            line: {
                events: {
                    legendItemClick: function () {
                        this.remove(true);
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
        }, {
            data: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
        }, {
            data: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
        }, {
            data: [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
        }]
    });

    var i = 5,
        chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    $('#button').click(function () {
        chart.addSeries({
            data: [i, i + 2, i + 4],
            index: i,
            name: 'Series ' + i
        });
        i++;
    });
});
```